# Nuxt3 - cannot build static app for development

Tags: vue.js, build, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm building a simple spa with Nuxt3, but it seems impossible to generate static files for development mode.

I'm using docker with a node:20 container to build the app via `npm run generate` and an nginx container to serve the files.

The app si "correctly" builded and served, but even if I set the env var `NODE_ENV=development` in the node container nuxt/nitro keep overriding it:

```
node@92e9e69997b1:~/app$ NODE_ENV=development npm run generate

> generate
> nuxt generate


 WARN  Changing NODE_ENV from development to production, to avoid unintended behavior.
```

The problem is, when i get errors at runtime I cannot use the chrome extension Vue Devtools to check since it self-disable for production compiled app

[image]

Comment: See https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vue-force-dev/oohfffedbkbjnbpbbedapppafmlnccmb

Comment: @EstusFlask that's a nice workaround, but I'd like to understand why the building process is overriding the environmental variable

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing more as well, but NODE_ENV affects node part of the app too, that's  possibly why. If your only goal is to access vue devtools then the extension is the preferable way

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you're not simply using `npm run dev`, it can run in your docker without any issues nah?